# Using PhoneGap to record audio to documents folder on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova

As part of an iPhone app I'm creating using PhoneGap, I need to be able to use the microphone to record to a new file which is sorted in the apps document folder on the phone.

I think I have the code sorted to actually capture the recording I'm just having trouble creating a blank .wav in the documents folder to record to.  According to the PhoneGap API iOS requires that the src file for the audio already exists.

Can anyone help my with the couple of lines of code needed to create this blank file?  My code so far is -

```
function recordAudio() {
    var src = "BLANK WAV IN DOCUMENTS FOLDER";
    var mediaRec = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);

    // Record audio
    mediaRec.startRecord();

    // Stop recording after 10 sec
    var recTime = 0;
    var recInterval = setInterval(function() {
        recTime = recTime + 1;
        if (recTime >= 10) {
            clearInterval(recInterval);
            mediaRec.stopRecord();
        }
    }, 1000);
}

function onSuccess() {
    console.log("recordAudio():Audio Success");
}

// onError Callback 
function onError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' + 
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}

$('#record-button').
bind('tap', function(){
    recordAudio();
})
```

Comment: Hi. I found your question and saw the answer you accepted. Can you please help me with an answer. Did you make this work on iOS using the code above and the code from the answer that was given?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to create the file first using the [File API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.4.1/phonegap_file_file.md.html#File).

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function onDeviceReady() {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, function fail(){});
}, false);

var gotFS = function (fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile("blank.wav",
        { create: true, exclusive: false }, //create if it does not exist
        function success(entry) {
            var src = entry.toURI();
            console.log(src); //logs blank.wav's path starting with file://
        },
        function fail() {}
    );
};
```

Comment: Hello. It doesn't seem to work with entry.toURI(). It only works when I use only entry. Do you know why is that happening?

Answer (score 0):

tried using something like this?
 `var src = "blank.wav";` instead of "BLANK WAV IN DOCUMENTS FOLDER" ?

Comment: Sorry, the "BLANK WAV IN DOCUMENTS FOLDER" is just a place holder for me.  I've tried to just set src = "blank.wav" but that doesn't work as iOS requires the file to be created first.

Comment: Try creating the file using FileWriter API? before you start recording http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileWriter