# Cordova record audio on ios9 does not work

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, audio, ios9.3

I am using Cordova to build an html5/JS app.

I have to record and play audio, so i use Media & File plug-ins, but i have problem to make it work on iOS.

**My steps :**

1)

I detect platform (Android or iOS).

If Android, no need to set anything, it works.

If Ios, I set the file URI to '../Library/NoCloud/' (after reading [Raymond Camden article](https://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/07/27/recording-and-saving-audio-in-cordova-applications/)),

then I create file before recording :

```
var mediaBaseUrl = '';
if(app.isIOS){
            mediaBaseUrl ='../Library/NoCloud/';
            createFileSystem();
}
```

My createFile function is :

```
createFileSystem : function(){
        var fileName= mediaBaseUrl+[myFileName];

        //asking for a new space
        window.requestFileSystem(
            LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 
            0, 

            //success 
            function(fileSystem){

                fileSystem.root.getFile(

                    fileName, 
                    { create: true, exclusive: false },

                    //success callback
                    function(){
                        console.log('ok file created');
                    }, 
                    null
                );
            },

            // error
            function() {
                console.log("***log: failed in creating media file in requestFileSystem");
            }
        );
    },
```

2) Once file is created, i create recorded file with Media constructor :

```
var recordedFile = new Media(
                mediaBaseUrl + [myFileName], 

                // success callback 
                function () {},

                // error callback
                function (err) {
                    console.log("recorded file error " );
                    console.log(err)
                }
            );
```

3) In config XML, i have this line to record in iOS Library Folder, and no save in Cloud :

```
  <preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Library" />
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
```

**My problem :**

On Android device, all is fine, i can record then listen audio file.

But on iOS device (ipad2), some things are strange :

- with my filename "../Library/NoCloud/myFileName", i have no success callback for fileSystem.root.getFile function, but i can see a file with the good name and the good place in my ipad Library/NoCloud folder, **except the file is empty.** So the Media constructor can not play the file and return an error.
- if i set myFileName as "myFileName", i have the callback of file creation ('ok file created'), but the Media constructor cannot access to the file and return the error :

  ```
  message: "Cannot use audio file from resource 'test.wav'", code: 1
  ```

I have checked ipad microphone, it is activated for this app. I believe it worked before the iOS update on ipad (now iOS 9.3.2), btu i am not sure anymore.
Is there something that i did wrong, or is there a new way to process ?

thanks !

Comment: I'm confused - why do you create the file *before* the recording? Shouldn't it be exactly the opposite?

Comment: Ok, ...i'm confused too :) I think I  was completely wrong in the way to think about the process : i thought that iOS need to write a file location before to "fill" it with the recorded data.. But  visibly it is not the case.  So if i understand now : one the system has recorded the audio data, i need to request the fileSystem function only for saving my recorded data ? thanks !

Comment: In fact, i read some articles before i wrote my code, for example this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9241157/using-phonegap-to-record-audio-to-documents-folder-on-ios      in which it is said to create a file reference before the creation of media file, beacuse ios needs a src that already exists... that's why i wrote that code...

Comment: Not sure what to say - I've not seen that to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include cdvfile://localhost/library-nosync/ with /Library/NoCloud

that is cdvfile://localhost/library-nosync//Library/NoCloud has to be given in the url sorce

Remember the url is given assuming library folder is inside www folder and it follows

This issue is being there from ios9 and after

Comment: Finally, this does not work with your trick. On the other hand, the problem was not here. I succeed in creating the file, but it was not recorded bu media plug in because of another media file (audio) which was played at the same time. When i did not play this file, recording is ok, (if i created the file before). It seems that access to record and play at the same time with cordova media plug-in is not possible on ios ? Thanks for your help.